# How to get logged in username in WebApi

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api

How to get a logged in username using Windows Authentication mode in a controller in Web Api.

I have set the Authentication Mode to Windows in config file.

I have used HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name and this.User.Identity.Name. Both of them are returning empty string.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If this.User.Identity.Name is an empty string, then you are not logged in.  Add the [Authorize] decorator to the top of the controller class, and you will start get 401: Unauthorized responses.